# Web development tools disappear when using THREE.js in Electron

Tags: javascript, three.js, electron

i'm pretty new to electron (and if anyone has a good documentation on it, please leave it as comment), and i face a problem tht i can't understand :

Everything is going well, until i load THREE.js library. Then, (even if my scene is rendered) web development tools (like js console etc...) are not available. Instead i get  blank page.

On the first picture, you can see this blank page, that should be like the right side of the second picture.
Can anybody help me to see through this ?

EDIT: After the first answer I add my main.js file :

```
var app = require('app');
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');

var mainWindow = null;

app.on('ready', function() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        height: 720,
        width: 1080,
        frame : false,
        resizable : false
    });

    mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/main.html');
});
```

(using npm 3.9.0)
[image: Blank Page instead of developer tools (on the right)]

[image: Here, with no THREE.js, everything works fine]

Comment: Did you try to update your current Chrome? What happens if you use another browser for example Firefox? Docs are [here](http://electron.atom.io/docs/) right?

Comment: I'm not using any browser : that's the purpose of electron (which will execute programs on a chromium setup) 
Using chrome or firefox, i have no problem, so i guess it is link to electron's chromium window...

Comment: Where is your console output? That's what you should post

Comment: @Zen I don't understand what you mean.. Your suggestion is about the question i should ask ?

Comment: Open the console of browser and post the error message

Comment: That's my problem, if i execute this on a browser, like chrome, everything is going well and i haven't any errors..

Comment: Have you tested three.js with chrome? What are steps to recreate this bug?

Comment: Yes, if i open it in chrome or mozilla, there is no problem, and i can't recreate this bug.
I've simply made a basic example of Three.js, that I put in the main.html of the main window of an basic Electron app (I'm trying to learn Electron and node.js). Both example, of Three and Electron are from the net, and seemed to be working, but kill chromium tools

Comment: @zen , By the way, thanks for trying to help ! Nobody seems to know an answer !

Comment: Maybe you should post a issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check in your `main.js` file if the line `win.webContents.openDevTools()` exists, if so delete it or comment it out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as I said, my main.js is the simplest, and there is no such line. I will edit my question to post my main.js

Comment: Because I was asking me what this line would do, I added it in my main.js. At the execution, the DevTools are present ! (So partially resolve my problems). However, if I try to close them and reopen them, I get my usual error. I'm asking myself, is it possible that  Babylon.js (and in fact I'm betting on WebGL) use a blocking thread, or doesn't release some mutex somewhere, which would block devtools from opening ?